# linking to a image not working due to css

Tags: html, css

i had a site like just eat setup on one domain name ive tranfered it to a sub domain name and edited all the files to update the url now ive noticed my background image is not working even tho im linking to it

```
<!-- banner part starts -->
<section class="hero bg-image" data-image-src="images/image01.jpg">
    <div class="hero-inner">
        <div class="container text-center hero-text font-white">
            <h1>Order Delivery & Take-Out </h1>
            <h5 class="font-white space-xs">Enter your postcode to find local restaurants and takeaways in your area</h5>
            <div class="banner-form">
```

live site can be found here http://food.clickincreaser.com/

Comment: You don't have a background image in your supplied source and site. What you have is an attribute `data-image-src` but not a `style='background-image=xxxx'`. I assume that your old site transformed the data-image-src to a background style somehow. If you look at the source of your old site you will see what it transforms to.

Comment: I presume that `data-image-src="images/image01.jpg"` is intended to set the background image via javascript but, the scripts are not loaded on the website. When you _"view page source"_ it shows this error _"Access denied for user 'geatzo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"_. I believe that's what causing the problem.

Comment: Changing that section to `<section class="hero bg-image" style="background-image:url('images/image01.jpg');">` seems to work, but it's hard to tell without looking at the previous site.

Comment: can you post this has the answer so i can make it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the:

```
data-image-src="images/image01.jpg">
```

To:

```
style="background-image: url(images/image01.jpg)">
```

To get something like that:

```
<section class="hero bg-image" style="background-image: url(images/image01.jpg)">
```